# tomcat 7 mssql connection error

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat

I have tomcat 7, Java 1.7, sqljdbc.jar in tomcat/lib and trying to connect MSSQL database. I tested database with JDBC connection and it is working perfect. When I am trying to configure with tomcat, I am getting null point error.

META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/APP_NAME">
<Resource name="jdbc/dbName" auth="Container"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    driverclassname="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    maxactive="10" maxidle="3" maxwait="10000" username="user"
    password="password" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://url;instanceName=myInstance;databaseName=dbName"
    removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="30" logAbandoned="true">
</Resource>
```

my web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dbName</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

I am testing connection with

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userDAO")
@SessionScoped
public class UserDAO {

@Resource(name="jdbc/AcapsRepo")
private DataSource ds;
public List<UserBean> getData() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

and throwing error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jpmc.acaps.repo.UserDAO.getData(UserDAO.java:37)
at com.jpmc.acaps.repo.UserDAO.main(UserDAO.java:120)
```

Comment: Do you ever initialize your DataSource ds object?